# Central compiling on a server

Tags: eclipse, liferay

We are a team that works on liferay in eclipse.
We want to code in our clients but when we want to compile or deploy our code, this process done by server(to lower usage of clients and send main process to server).
How this can be possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rundeck](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin) plugin for Jenkins to trigger a deploy based on the SCM commit message.

So your team would code and commit to a repository. Jenkins will then compile and deploy the latest build on the server.

BUT: I think I'd prefer to run my code on my client before committing it.